# Inequality using Operator norm with differential of Matrix Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-norms

I'm trying to show that

> Inequality $\,\| A^2 − B^2 \| ≤ 2\|A − B\|\,$ holds,
> where $\|\cdot\|$ is the Operator norm, and $A,B \in \mathbb R^{n,n}\,$ with $\|A\| < 1$ and $\| B\|  < 1$.

I've shown that for
$F(A)=A^{2}$ the differential is $\big(F'(A)\big)(H)=AH+HA$.

How can I show that
$\|F'(X)\| \leq 2$ for $ X \in \{A+t(B-A)\mid t \in [0,1]\}$ ?

Comment: Can you please edit, remove the nonsense symbols, and make things so that they are understandable?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\|F'(X)H\|=\|XH+HX\|\leq\|XH\|+\|HX\|\leq\|X\|\|H\|+\|H\|\|X\|=2\|X\|\|H\|$$
Furthermore for $X\in \{A+t(B-A)\mid t\in[0,1]\}$ we have $$\|X\|= \|(1-t)A+tB\|\leq\|(1-t)A\|+\|tB\|<(1-t)+t=1$$
Hence $\|F'(X)\|<2$.

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot of sense, im still struggling with the fact that $\|F´(X)H\| \leq 2\|X\|\|H\|$ and $\|X\| < 1$ implies $\|F´(X)\|<2$, wouldn't $\|H\| \leq 1$ be needed?

Comment: Note that by definition we have $$\|F'(X)\|=\sup_{H\ne0}\frac{\|F'(X)H\|}{\|H\|}$$ We showed that $\|F'(X)H\|<2\|H\|$, so the supremum above simplifies to $\|F'(X)\|<2$ (actually in general we only get '$\leq$', but since we are in the finite-dimensional case the supremum is a maximum, hence we get strict inequality)

Comment: That's what I was missing, thanks !